# How to display results in input field from td tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, html-table

my title may be hard to understand but i didnt know how to ask this question so let me explain. Here is my script

`$(this).parent("td").siblings("td:last").text(intTotal);`

This script display results inside td tag `<td></td>`.. How do i make the intTotal to display inside input field `<input id="total">` please note i have many rows and i tried using `$("#total").val(intTotal)` but this can only work if i had 1 row.

Here is the rest of the script

```
    var strClass = $(this).prop("class");
    var intTotal = 1;
    $.each($("input:text." + strClass), function () {
        var intInputValue = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(intInputValue))
        {
            intTotal = intTotal * intInputValue;
        }
    });
    $(this).parent("td").siblings("td:last").text(intTotal);
});
```

Thank You

Comment: How about $(this).parent("td").siblings("td:last").empty().append(intTotal);

Comment: Please, provide some HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code below sends the results to the last element of the td.

```js
$(this).parent("td").siblings("td:last").text(intTotal);
```

To assign a value inside an element using jQuery, you must first select it and then edit its content using the `html()`, `text()`, `val()`... functions.

In your case, the code below will update the value of the input with the #total id.

```js
$("#total").val(intTotal);
```

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is i have many rows that script can only work if i had 1 row.

Comment: Do you have more than one input element with the same id? if so this is wrong.